# How can I download Fancy Pants Adventures for offline play?

Tags: flash, fancy-pants-adventures

[Fancy Pants](http://www.teagames.com/games/fancypants2/play.php) is one of the best flash games ever.

[image]

Is there some way to download it, so that I can play it offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click and "Save As" this direct link to download the game: [The link](http://armorgames.com/files/games/the-fancy-pants-adve-553.swf)

Comment: Thanks! this one works with no problems. Do you know what the problem is with [what Oak says](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/724/how-can-i-download-this-flash-game-for-offline-play/726#726)?

Comment: There could be some restrictions inside the other SWF. I'm glad that your problem solved. You can tick my answer as accepted.

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: How did you get the `.swf` link? I can use that info for some of the other games that I want to download. thanks!

Comment: I always use Firefox to do that. You can do it as Oak explained in his answer. For the objects you can't download by this method such as Flash videos, you can use the Firefox addon "FlashGot": https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/220/

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: I did it [as Oak explained](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/724/how-can-i-download-this-flash-game-for-offline-play/726#726) and got [some problems](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/743). Thats why I wanted to know how you found the link to the file you posted in your answer...

Comment: I searched for and found the official maker of the game (Armor games).

Answer (score 7):

Usually if you download the .swf file, you can activate it offline; though some games prevent it.

How to download the .swf in Firefox: right-click the page, select "view page info", choose the "media" tag, search for the .swf file and save it with the "save as" button.

Once the .swf file is downloaded, you can open it in your favorite browser (click file->open, or just drag it in) and it should work.

Comment: I downloaded it, but its not working as expected. Please see [this question that I posted](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/743).

Comment: @Lazer: I don't know, I suggest checking if it's specific to that game or is a problem with flash on your computer in general. Try downloading some simple flash animation this way and check if it works. Notice that this will NOT work for anything which uses streaming (such as flash video players).

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip/alternative method:

Even if you don't use it on a regular basis, Internet Explorer is the best to get files like videos and flash from websites, because it asks for no extra plug-in or add-on. It stores everything in the "Temporary Internet Files" folder. You can just wait for the game to load in it, and then get it on this location on your computer:

1. Open either Microsoft Internet Explorer or the Windows Control Panel.
2. In Microsoft Internet Explorer, open the Tools menu and choose the Internet Options... menu. In Control Panel. open the Internet Options list item. In either case, a new window titled "Internet Properties" appears.
3. In the Temporary Internet Files section of the Internet Properties window, click the "Settings..." button. A new "Settings" window appears.
4. In the "Settings" window, click the "View Files..." button. After a brief delay, a new Windows Explorer window appears. This window displays all of the Temporary Internet Files stored on the computer and their location on the local hard drive. The window also displays the URL where each temporary file came from.

   All youtube video\flash games you've played are stored here for some time.
   There will also be a lot of other files like images and scripts and stuff...use the search bar to filter and show .swf files only. The title of the file should be something like the title of the game. If you can't find it by title, you can find it by the internet adress which is on a column nearby.
5. After you find the correct one, copy it to the desktop (or any folder you prefer) and run it. You now have the offline game for playing.

***Note***: If you ever clean your "temporary internet files", or use pc-boosters like NitroPc or CCleaner, the files might be deleted from the location, and you need to access the file on the net again.

Comment: LOL i didn't see it was so old...sorry :D

Comment: Haha but still valid - I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

With the [discontinuation of flash in 2020](https://www.theverge.com/2020/12/31/22208190/adobe-flash-is-dead), there are two ways to play Fancy Pants Adventures offline.

**Option 1 - Flashpoint Archive**

Fancy Pants Adventures: World 1, 2, 3, and 4 can be played in their original form through [Flashpoint Archive](https://flashpointarchive.org/). Simply download the application, and search for Fancy Pants Adventure.

**Option 2 - The Fancy Pants Adventures: Classic Pack**

The original developer has released [The Fancy Pants Adventures: Classic Pack](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1668460/The_Fancy_Pants_Adventures_Classic_Pack/), which includes Fancy Pants Adventures: Worlds 1, 2, and 3 for $9.99. World 1 & World 2 are updated to run in widescreen at 60fps. According to [an interview with PCGamer](https://www.pcgamer.com/games/action/this-flash-developer-is-battling-18-years-of-legacy-code-to-bring-my-childhood-favorite-platformers-to-steam/), these versions are based on the original game's source code.