# How to open a .swf game file?

Tags: flash

I have a .swf game with me. How do I play it?

- Though I am able to play the game from the website I downloaded it from, if I open the .swf file in the browser, I just get a grey colored screen.
- Opening the file in Adobe Flash Player 10 also gives me the same grey screen.
- I am able to open the file through [GOM Player](http://www.gomlab.com/eng/GMP_download.html), there is some difference in the gameplay - for example the boundaries are not well defined - the jumps below the ground are not as good.

What is a good player to open a .swf game file?

Comment: Please note that depending on the type of game, there might be other (external) dependencies to the game (e.g., external files, server-side calls, other swfs), or the swf might just be some sort of wrapper for the game. Without more information on what the game is, it will be hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

Adobe Flash Player will always be the best way. If it only shows a grey screen, there might be other things it relies on. Can you show the entire source of the tag you got it from? So the `<embed>` tag.

Comment: I am talking about [this game](http://www.teagames.com/games/fancypants2/play.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Standalone Flash Player](http://www.standaloneflashplayer.com/).

> The most important feature of this
>   software is that it can support both
>   Flash in the SWF format and FLV
>   format. Files in the SWF format,
>   traditionally called "ShockWave Flash"
>   movies, "Flash movies" or "Flash
>   games", usually have a .swf file
>   extension and may be an object of a
>   web page, strictly "played" in this
>   Standalone Flash Player.

Comment: The download link on that page is corrupt.

Comment: Try this link: http://www.softsea.com/download.php?id=834076721

Comment: By the way, I tried to play the game offline on my IE and Firefox browsers, and there were no problems.

Comment: I can repro the asker's issue.

Comment: I can reproduce it as well. Gotta be an issue with the game somehow.

Comment: I would NOT recommend downloading the standalone player from a third-party site. Instead, download it directly from Adobe's website: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html (it is known as "Projector" on their site, no need to use the "content debugger", just the plain projector will do)

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with the game's file itself. Today's SWF files can spawn several files and load external ressources (e.g. another swf file or images, videos, etc.). Maybe you're missing these files (some flash game platforms might provide a loader that later on loads the actual game - it's possible you grabbed such a loader only).

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with your current version of installed Adobe Flash Player. I tried to play the game offline on my IE and Firefox browsers, and there were no problems. I recommend you to install the latest version of [Adobe Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

Comment: I have the same problem, and I do have the latest version of Adobe Flash (not Player).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, [iSwiff](http://echoone.com/iswiff/) is a free application that allows you to open .swf files.